# SQL ON SINGLE TABLE GROUP BY LIMIT 10

Tags: sql, group-by, limit

I have a table with items (id_item, name, category, stock,...)
I'd like make a query to group by result on category and LIMIT 10 first items which are in this category

Is it possible?

Comment: How do you define "first items"?  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering unless you specify what ordering you want.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: order was not important in my case but Gordon gave me the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select i.*
from (select i.*,
             row_number() over (partition by category order by ?) as seqnum
      from items i
     ) i
where seqnum <= 10;
```

The `?` is for the column that specifies what YOU mean by "first".